# nvcc unknown option -no_pie

Tags: macos, gcc, cuda, ld, nvcc

After updating CUDA on my mac(Snow Leopard) nvidia's nvcc compiler acting strange, when compiling this:

```
 nvcc batched_gemm.cu
```

I get the following compile error, and I have no idea how to fix the problem.

```
ld: unknown option: -no_pie
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having done an update, I assume is to the latest stable (v4.1), so according to

> NVIDIA CUDA **Toolkit v4.1** Production Release Notes for Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X, CUDA Toolkit **Known Issues**, **MAC 10.**7:
>
> The host linker on Mac OS 10.7 generates position-independent executables by default. As CUDA does not support position-independent executable currently, the linker must generate position-dependent executable by passing in the -no_pie option. If nvcc is being used to link the application, this option will be passed to the linker by default. To override the default behavior, **the -Xlinker -pie option can be passed to nvcc**.